# jquery next button focus

Tags: asp.net, jquery

To improve navigation on one of the pages I am tyring to set a focus on a next available(enabled) button when leaving last data entry field.

```
$('input[type=text], select, textarea').filter(':last').blur(function()
    {

        $('input[type=submit][type=button]:enabled:first').focus();

    });
```

For some reason it only works when last data entry field is textbox. Something is wrong in the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(':text,textarea,select').filter(':last').blur(function() 
    { 
        $(':button,submit:enabled:first').focus(); 
    }); 
});

<body>
  <textarea rows="3" /></textarea>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>  
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="button" value="Something" />
</body>
```

Did the trick ... pretty much identical, so I don't know what's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

$('input').filter(':last').blur(function() 
    {

```
    $('input:enabled:first').focus(); 

});
```

doesn't do the trick?

Comment: Thanks for reply. No, it won't because buttons are also 'input' elements.

Comment: So you want focus on the next input type that isn't a button? I misread the question (seemed like you wanted focus on the next button from a button).

'input[type=text][type=select][type=textarea]' seems that it should work though (and so does your current handler)

Comment: I want to focus on next input type that IS a button, but with this snippet it seems it can focus on next textbox, or whatever is first

Comment: Bah, I can't figure out how to put code in a comment, reposted as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the buttons a CSS class and try  $('.ButtonClass:enabled:first').focus();